# How to get which element was clicked and the src attribute of said element in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox

I have an iframe that's generated on-the-fly with the [fancybox plugin](http://fancybox.net/). I want to get the clicked element inside of it and from that element get the src attribute but whenever I try I just get "undefined" as an answer.

what triggers the iframe creation is:

```
<a id="contentImageAJAX" class="iframe" href="/tools/images?keyword=cat" style="display:none;">g</a>
```

and

```
 $('#contentImage').focus(function(){
        var $contentImage = $('#contentImage');
        $('a#contentImageAJAX').click().fancybox({
            'width' :  1280,
            'height': 600,
            'centerOnScroll': true,
            'hideOnContentClick' : true,
            'onCleanup': function(){tryMe($contentImage);}
        });
```

I found out that the iframe created is #fancybox-frame so I tried:

```
$('#fancybox-frame').load(function(){
    $('#fancybox-frame').contents().find('body').html('Hey, i`ve changed content of <body>! Yay!!!');
});
```

but it didn't work and "tryMe" is this function:

```
function tryMe($cImg){
        console.log($('#fancybox-frame').contents().find('clickable').attr('src'));
    }
```

I've been trying several iterations of this for hours any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The selector inside `tryMe` method is is wrong `find('clickable')`. I think you are looking for `find('.clickable')`.

Try this

```
$('a#contentImageAJAX').click().fancybox({
            'width' :  1280,
            'height': 600,
            'centerOnScroll': true,
            'hideOnContentClick' : true,
            'onCleanup': function(){parent.tryMe($contentImage);},
            'onComplete': function(){
               $('#fancybox-frame').contents().find('linkSelector').click(function(){
                   //Do you stuff here.
               });
            } 
 });
```

Comment: I changed `find('clickable')`to `find('.clickable')` and I got the src of 1 image but how can I get the one that was clicked? also I'm getting this error 183Error in event handler for 'undefined': Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1

Comment: You have to attach a click event handler to get the `src` of the image you click.

Comment: an inline onclick? really? even though it's bad practice?

Comment: You can attach a click handler to a link inside iframe also. I didnt say to do it inline.

Comment: I realize that but then I'm unsure as to how to proceed, would you mind telling me how'd you go to do that? sorry about assuming you meant inline :)

Comment: Check my edited answer, replace the appropriate selector in place of `linkSelector` and it should work fine.

Comment: I did the changes and changed the selector to the appropiate one `.clickable` but it wouldn't make an alert appear. =/

Comment: @ShankarSangoli let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2854/discussion-between-luis-armando-and-shankarsangoli)